# How to create an array with dynamic size at runtime in Ballerina?

Tags: arrays, size, dynamic-arrays, ballerina

It seems currently it only allows compile-time constants for the array size in the array type descriptor.
E.g.

```php
const ARR_SIZE = 2;

public function main() {
    int[] arr1 = []; // okay
    int[2] arr2 = []; // okay
    int[ARR_SIZE] arr3 = []; // okay
    int array_size = 4;
    // int[array_size] arr4 = []; // not okay, gives compilation error: "invalid reference expression 'array_size' as array size: expected a constant reference expression"
}
```

What is the easiest way to create an array whose size is not a compile time constant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As seen in the question, the array type descriptor only allows compile-time constants for the array size. Hence, there is no way to create a fixed length array whose size is only known at runtime.

What you can do is creating a variable length array and changing its length at runtime. If the array type has a [filler value](https://ballerina.io/spec/lang/master/#FillMember), the easiest and the fastest way to expand an array to a particular length at runtime is to use the array member assignment statement or you can use the `array:setLength` function.

```php
import ballerina/io;
import ballerina/lang.array;

public function main() {
    int array_size = 4;
    int[] arr = [];
    arr[array_size - 1] = 1;
    io:println(arr); // [0,0,0,1]

    array:setLength(arr, array_size + 3);
    io:println(arr); // [0,0,0,1,0,0,0]

    arr.setLength(array_size - 1);
    io:println(arr); // [0,0,0]
}
```

Otherwise we have to push members to the array until we get the required size.

```php
import ballerina/io;

public function main() {
    int array_size = 4;
    string:Char[] arr = [];
    // arr[array_size - 1] = "0"; // error: "array of length 0 cannot be expanded into array of length 4 without filler values"

    foreach int i in 0..<array_size {
        arr.push("0");
    }
    io:println(arr); // ["0","0","0","0"]
}
```

Comment: I think we also need to answer to how to make sure that the array won't grow beyond a certain size.